# CSS/ (text-emphasis:dot) not function when applying font imported by URL

Tags: html, css

I want to use both (text-emphasis: dot) and (font imported by external url),
but in web, it doesn't show both. When I use `text-emphasis:dot`, font doesn't be applied
Also, When I use font, `text-emphasis:dot` doesn't be applied. More strangely, When I apply font, `text-emphasis:circle` and seasame can be applied.
I want to apply `text-emphasis:dot` with font imported by url. Help me please...!

```html
<style>
@font-face{
  src: url("BMYEONSUNG_ttf.ttf");
  font-family : "ys";
}
.font_ys{
  font-family : "ys";
}
.font_dot {
      text-emphasis: dot;
      -webkit-text-emphasis: dot red;
      color: #e94e77;
      )
</style>
<span class="font_dot font_ys">AAA</span>BBBB
```

Comment: I am not seeing the problem (though I am loading  a different font as I don't have the one you are using). Could you put up a working version so we can see the problem for ourselves?

Comment: I have found the BMYEONSUNG_ttf font and am now seeing your problem. I guess it's related to the actual font, not the fact that it was loaded via font-face.

Answer (score 0):

Text emphasis doesn't work in major browsers today